# how I make <a> to show me alone element with a filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

This is the code I want to filter 'marcas' when I click to  ....

```
<body ng-controller="marcasController">

<a>Chevrolet</a>
<a>Renault</a>

<ul ng-repeat="marca in marcas">
    <li ng-repeat="tipo in marca.modelo">{{tipo.nombre}}</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

---show me alone renault or chevrolet depends to where do click---

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('marcasController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.marcas =[

{
  "nombre": "Chevrolet",
  "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
  "modelo": [
    {"nombre":"aveo", "color":"black"},
    {"nombre":"corsa", "color":"yellow"}
    ],
  "tab": "aveo"
},
{
  "nombre": "Renault",
  "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
  "modelo": [
    {"nombre":"clio", "color":"black"},
    {"nombre":"sandero", "color":"red"}
    ],
  "tab": "aveo"
},
];

}])
```

show me alone renault or chevrolet depends to where do click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use, for example

```
<a ng-click="marcas.selected = 'Renault'">Renault</a>
```

and

```
<ul ng-repeat="marca in marcas | filter:{nombre:marcas.selected}">...</ul>
```

---

*Before posting a question on SO, you should first try to create your own solution and then include your attempt(s) in the question.*

Comment: [`<a ng-click="marcas.selected = ''">...</a>`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGMgw) _And ... come on, have you tried anything before asking for help again?_